# If statement variables

Tags: python, variables

So I've been trying to make this turn-based battle and I ran into a slight issue. I can't seem to use the variables that are defined within the if statement. I tried declaring them global but that didn't work. Is there any way to solve this problem while still using if statements?

Here the code that I'm having issues with:

```
import time
from random import randint
import copy
health = randint(100, 400)
speed = randint(50, 100,)
damage = randint(50, 200)

totalhealth = copy.deepcopy(health)

def stats():
    print("Damage:",damage)
    print("Health:",totalhealth, "|", health)
    print("Speed:",speed)
if spawn == "mandrake":
        spawnh = 200
        spawnspeed = 50
        spawnspeed = 50
        eelement = "earth" 
        buff = "heal self"
        gold = randint(10,20)
        ms = 3

x = True
ss = 0
s = 0
ms = 0 
m = 0
spawn = "mandrake"
while x == True:
    battle = input("""
    Inventory(1)
    Run(2)
    Attack(3)
    Defend(4)
    Skills(5)""")
    stats()
    if battle ==  '3':
     
        if ss > 99 and spawnh > 0:
            print(spawn, "dealt", spawndamage)
            time.sleep(3)
            ss  -= 100
            health = health - spawndamage
            ms += 1
        
        if s >= 100:
            print("you dealt", damage)
            time.sleep(3)
            spawnh = spawnh - damage
            s -= 100
        
        if s <= 100 and spawnh > 0:
            print("you prepare to attack")
            time.sleep(3)
            s += speed
            if ss <= 100 and spawnh > 0:
                print(spawn, "prepares to attack")
                ss += spawnspeed 
            if ss >= 100 and spawnh > 0:
                print(spawn, "dealt", damage)
                time.sleep(3)
                ss = ss - 100
                health = health - spawndamage
        
        if health <= 0:
            print("you died!")
            time.sleep(3)
          
            
        if spawnh <= 0:
            print("you are victorious!")
            x = False
          
     if spawnspeed < 100 and spawnh > 0:
        print(spawn, "prepares to attack")
        ss += spawnspeed
     if health <= 0:
        print("you died!")
        time.sleep(3)
        exit()

        exit()
     if spawnh <= 0:
        print("you are victorious!")
        x = False
```

Comment: What is the ```spawn``` variable? Also, you have defined ```spawnspeed=50``` twice. I think one of them should be ```spawndamage```

Comment: _"I can't seem to use the variables... "_ doesn't give us any useful information on your problem. If you're getting a python error, please post the entire stack trace. If not, then post the output or behaviour you're getting, and the one you were expecting.

Comment: what is the value of `spawndamage` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a variable before it's been declared.
You've got `if spawn == "mandrake":` before you declare spawn, move `spawn = "mandrake"` above the if statement.